# TexMaker - working with multiple tex files, autocomplete is not working

Tags: cross-referencing, texmaker, include

**Background**:

The document that I am currently writing is getting pretty big, so I decided to split it.

I've tried `\include` and `\input` commands, but the problem still remains to be solved.

I have split Chapter one to `file 1.tex` from the main document, and include it with the mentioned commands (tried both).

Main file is marked as Master.

I am having cross referencing (equations, labels and so on) between different sections.

**Problem**

In `file 1.tex`, I am referencing `labels` and `equations` from different parts on the main document - before and after the `\include` command.

However, the auto-complete is only working for `labels` and `equations` that are mentioned before `\include` command, but not working for the ones which are inserted in main file after `\include` command.

Is there any way to fix this?

MWE:

Main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{1st}
\begin{equation}
    a=1
    \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
all the equations of the paper: \ref{eq:1}, \ref{eq:2}, \ref{eq:3}

\include{2}

\section{3rd}
\begin{equation}
    a=3
    \label{eq:3}
\end{equation}
all the equations of the paper: \ref{eq:1}, \ref{eq:2}, \ref{eq:3}
\end{document}
```

2.tex:

```
\section{2st}
\begin{equation}
    a=2
    \label{eq:2}
\end{equation}
all the equations of the paper: \ref{eq:1}, \ref{eq:2}, \ref{eq:3}
```

**In Main.tex autocomplete is working (when writing \ref...) for all 3 equations, but in 2.tex auto-complete is working only for the second one.**

Comment: How many times have you run `pdflatex`?

Comment: I have set it up to run like: pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex

Comment: Is it possible to include a small [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which can reproduce your situation: In this way you may solve the problem easily also. BTW Latest version of TeXmaker is [4.0.3](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html)

Comment: Do you mean the auto-complete in Texmaker, or the compiled pdf? If in Texmaker, the autocomplete will not work because Texmaker doesn't know that you've defined those commands in a different file. I don't know of a way to get it to parse those commands and allow auto-complete.

Comment: Yes, darthbith, I am talking about auto-complete in tex files.

Comment: texenthusiast, I added the MWE in main window.

Comment: Yes, you are right, The `\label{eq:1}` and `\label{eq:3}` in `main.tex` is not available for auto-completion in `2.tex` incase you wish [report/contribute](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list) this strange issue with same MWE. But i did not encounter this problem if you place `\section{1st}` in `child1.tex`, `\section{2nd}` in `child2.tex` and `\section{3rd}` in `child3.tex` auto-completion works perfectly. Then new `main.tex` has only `\include{child1.tex}\include{child2.tex}\include{child3.tex}`

Comment: texenthusiast, thank You. But, with your suggestion (I tried this already) autocompletion is not working in Child1, if you want to reference somthing from Child2 and Child3 in it.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to address this: you say `file 1.tex` in the op, but later on `1.tex`. In case you have a space in the file name, delete it and put in a dash instead. Or an underscore.

Answer (score 3):

> Have your main document in the current editing window. Now select Options-Define Current >Document as "Master Document". This will do what you are asking for, I just did it. Also, now you can compile from any of the files and it will work.

Just worked for me, thanks heaps. That was really annoying me. Much happier now...

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is one of the major shortcommings of TM and TS. My guess is that is it looking in the `.aux` file of the current file. If there are any `\@input{file.aux}`
 it will look there too.

But this means, when you are in `2.tex` the rest of the document is not referenced in this particular `.aux`.

Then a master document is set, TM really ought to go back to the master files `.aux` when it is looking for labels and such.

What happens if you are not using `\include`?

EDIT:

Just tested it using the latest TM. No luck. It seems even worse. It is looking directly at `\label`'s in `2.tex`.

Try adding

```
\newcommand\test[1]{\label{#1}}
```

and in `2.tex` replace `\label{eq:2}` by `\test{eq:2}`. Now TM cannot find any labels.

As already mentioned, it really should be looking that the `.aux` files instead. It will miss `label=key` in `listings` etc.

Personally I use Emacs, and I'm actually not quite sure where it gets its label information, but it does handle multiple files just fine (it may also be looking for `\label`).

Answer (score 1):

As previously answered, Texmaker does not seem to reference labels declared in included files in the structure of the document.

A workaround that you can use, however, is to use the way Texmaker detects existing labels to trick it into thinking that you are declaring a label inside your document when you are, in fact, not.

Let me explain by reusing your MWE.

Main.tex :

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\ProvideLabels#1{}
\def\LabelsAvailable#1{}
\begin{document}
\section{1st}
\begin{equation}
    a=1
    \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
all the equations of the paper: \ref{eq:1}, \ref{eq:2}, \ref{eq:3}

\include{2}\ProvideLabels{\label{eq:2}}

\section{3rd}
\begin{equation}
    a=3
    \label{eq:3}
\end{equation}
all the equations of the paper: \ref{eq:1}, \ref{eq:2}, \ref{eq:3}
\end{document}
```

2.tex :

```
\LabelsAvailable{\label{eq:1}\label{eq:3}}
\section{2st}
\begin{equation}
    a=2
    \label{eq:2}
\end{equation}
all the equations of the paper: \ref{eq:1}, \ref{eq:2}, \ref{eq:3}
```

Adding `\def\ProvideLabels#1{}` and `\def\LabelsAvailable#1{}` in the preamble of the document creates two commands to which you can pass arguments and that do nothing with it. In other words, whatever you write in it, only Texmaker will be interested in it, as it does not rely on proper latex compiling to see whether the `\label{stuff}` you wrote will actually be used by latex.

Now, you can use `\ProvideLabels{\label{label1} \label{label2}}` in your main document after calling a `\include` to explain to Texmaker which labels were created within what you included. 
In the same logic, you can use `\LabelsAvailable{\label{label1} \label{label2}}` within your included documents to explain Texmaker what labels have been created either in your main document or in other included documents.

You can use the same logic to explain to Texmaker the structure of the document itself, but usually, it is less important when writing the document.

I do realize that this solution is very high maintenance, very hacky and absolutely non ideal, but I could myself not find better. 
Ideally, of course, Texmaker should simply be more clever about this kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

"Edit" menu of Texmaker -> "Refresh structure"

(and of course the file 1.tex is supposed to be 2.tex...)

Comment: user27168, thank You. I have already tried it, however - with no luck... And of course, 2.tex it is...

Answer (score 0):

Have your main document in the current editing window. Now select Options-Define Current Document as "Master Document". This will do what you are asking for, I just did it. Also, now you can compile from any of the files and it will work.

Comment: Sorry, but as You may see from the previous answer - this does not help.