# TEXmaker. After about 10000 lines loose control over begin{document} and end{document}

Tags: texmaker

When I start with a small program I have no problems with the begin{document} and  end{document} statements. When I add another 7000 lines of code, still no problems. When I add about 10000 lines I loose all control over the begin- and end{document} statements.
The moment I try to put the cursor on one of these two lines the text file shuts down and even TEXmaker shuts down.
When I want to put the cursor on these two lines, the cursor is not visible.
When I restart TEXmaker the program that shut down is not visible in the list of ''recently opened''.
Hope anyone can help.

Comment: I have no idea about texmaker but you don't need to have 7000 lines in a single file, you can put each section in a separate file and have your main document `\input{..}` each section.

Comment: I do not know your project, but @DavidCarlisle is most likely right, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include.

Comment: (Educated guess based on the behaviour of TeXstudio:) When you place your cursor on a `\begin{...}` statement, your editor automatically highlights the corresponding `\end{..}` statement (or vice versa). This means it has to parse all the lines in between. 10000 is probably the upper limit where either your computer or the program itself can't handle it anymore. As others said, your best option is to split the big file into multiple smaller ones and use `\input` or `\include`.

Comment: Working with separate files can be a nightmare when cross-referencing : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126980/texmaker-working-with-multiple-tex-files-autocomplete-is-not-working