# Cross-referencing between different .tex filex

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters

I have a document with multiple chapters written in seperate .tex files. I want to cross reference figures/tables/sections between the .tex files.

So the structure would be:

fulldocument.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\include{chapter1.tex}
\include{chapter2.tex}

\end{document}
```

chapter1.tex

```
\section{start} \label{sec:start}

\ref{here I would like to cross-reference to a table/section/figure from chapter2.tex}
```

chapter2.tex

```
\section{beginning} \label{sec:beginning}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{description}
\label{tab:table1}
\begin{tabular}

asdf

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, when using `\ref`-command in chapter1.tex I can only choose the labels from chapter1.tex but not from the other document.

I have looked up the already existing question here ([Cross-referencing between different files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/cross-referencing-between-different-files) ) but this suggestion does not work, since I get the error that `\usepackage{xr-hyper}`is only allowed in the preamble, which is not the case here, since the preamble in my structure is only in fulldocument.tex, not in the other .tex files.

Has someone a solution for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no you can use `\label`/`\ref` across the whole document. You do not need xr (or xr-hyper)

Comment: perhaps your editor has problems to show you the labels, but you can simply type `\ref{tab:table1}`

Comment: Using TexMaker this helped me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126980/texmaker-working-with-multiple-tex-files-autocomplete-is-not-working